# Freeze/buzzing sound, is it possibly related to an External HDD

Tags: windows, hard-drive, freeze

On my windows 10 desktop Gaming PC, I very infrequently get a very brief freezing and buzzing sound like you would expect before a BSOD (But the BSOD never happens). However, this has only seemingly happened when I try to play games loaded from my External HDD, connected through a USB to my desktop, which has had some notoriously slow load times (due to being an HDD).

Just wondering if anyone knows if it's possible that the External HDD could be the problem, and if so, how to check. I've looked in the event viewer and I just don't see anything related to it in system errors from the time the Freezing happens, but I could be looking in the wrong area. Thanks. I've also scanned the External HDD for any possible errors and it didn't pick up any.

Comment: Is the buzzing coming from the computer or the external HDD?

Comment: The sound isn't from anything hardware related, I think, because it emanates from speakers or earbuds, whichever I'm using when the freeze happens.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything to worry about.  USB HDDs are slow, and the brief freezing usually indicates that the computer is waiting for something, like the data from the drive.  A brief pause is to be expected when loading data in my experience, at least.  As long as there are no disc errors, you should be fine.

I don't know what's causing the buzzing, but I doubt it's indicative of a problem.  It's likely just a product of the freezing.